# Mod Arithmetic, involving multiplication.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$(12\cdot 53 ) \bmod 32$

In the above case, if I multiple 12 by 53 and then take mod then what is the use of modular arithmetic. 
The other way is:

$(12\cdot 53 ) mod 32 = (12 mod 32 = 12) + (53 mod 32 = 21)$ but the sum is 33 which is not correct.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Do you mean $12 \times 53 \mod 32$ or $12^{53} \mod 32 ? $ If the former , you can simply multiply the terms and find the remainder.

Comment: Writing run on "equations" like "(12* 53 ) mod 32 = 12 mod 32 = 12 + 53 mod 32 = 21" makes no sense and it is very confusing.  In this case, I think every one of those equal signs is false.

Comment: I found the property: (12* 53 ) mod 32] i.e.(12 mod 32) * (53 mod 32)] mod 32 =[12 + 21] mod 32 = 1.

Comment: Answer is not correct, somebody please guide me why is the property: (a* b) mod n = [(a mod n) * (b mod n)] mod n : not working?

Comment: you multiply the remainders not add.

Comment: If you have further questions after reading the linked answers then reply here (or there).

Comment: [(12* 53 ) mod 32 ]mod 32= [(12mod 32) * (53 mod 32)] mod 32 = [12 * 21] mod 32 =  252 mod 32 = 28. @Bill: I have questions with multiplication, I would read your post first.

Comment: @zak  Yes, that is correct. Below is another way, using the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to simplify arithmetic $$\begin{align} \bmod 8\!:&\ \ \ \ \overbrace{3\cdot 53}^{\large\!\!\!\!\!\! \equiv\ 3\ \cdot\ 5}\equiv 7\\ \overset{\large \times\ 4}\Rightarrow\,\bmod 32\!:&\ \ 12\cdot 53\equiv 4\cdot 7\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$